# SAP Logon connection with VBA automation error

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have the following code for connecting SAP logon with VBA

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim SAPapplication, Connection, session As Object
Set SAPGUIAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")

Set SAPapplication = SAPGUIAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SAPapplication.Children(0)

Set session = Connection.Children(0)

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "******"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

The code works perfectly if I have login through my credentials in the SAP system.
But it gives following error, when I try login through other credentials.

> Run-time error '-2147221020 (800401e4)':
>
> Automation error 
> Invalid syntax
> [image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: For this code to work the pre-requsite is a running SAP session

Comment: yes the SAP session is already open when i am starting to run the code

Comment: What should one imagine under other credentials?

Comment: At which line does the error occur? I assume `Set SAPGUIAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")`. If yes then SAPLOGON is not started and you do not have a running SAP session

Comment: @Storax :  i do have session open and yes i am facing error at the line you have mentioned

Comment: That can't be unless the session is not local and you connect via a terminal server to SapGui

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The respective user was using SAP Logon via Citrix, and hence VBA didn't find SAPGUI. SAP LOGON needs to be started locally.